# cant inject http in angular2

Tags: http, angular, typescript

I'm trying to inject the http module inside my angular2 app but I'm getting the error.

> Unexpected value 'Http' imported by the module 'AppModule'

This is what I'm trying.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Http],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is how I try to use it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        Maintenance Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="htmlToPublish.title"/>
        <textarea [(ngModel)]="htmlToPublish.html" rows="10" cols="50">Write here the HTML code that you want to publish
        </textarea> 
        <button (click)="sendHtml()">Publish</button>
       <p>
       {{htmlToPublish}}
       </p>
 `,
})

export class AppComponent  {

   constructor(public http: Http){

   } 

   name = 'Angular'; 
   htmlToPublish: HtmlPage

   public sendHtml() {
   // Here I want to use http that I injected in constructor

   }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `HttpModule` to imports to get `Http` provided

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; // <<< changed
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule], // <<< changed
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but where you inject `Http` you need

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a bit confusing for me that you import one thing in the NgModule and another different in the component. I didn't know this have changed

Comment: `Http` is just the most common used class, but it consists of a bunch of classes. Previously this was `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, not it's `HttpModule`.